# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined on mergeMap Observable when page refreshed

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, observable, angular-services

I'm facing this problem where when I call the following method to subscribe upon page refresh, the error "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" occurs

Here are my imports:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
```

Here's my method which is causing the error when I refresh the page:

```
getChildSubItem(subItemTag:string): Observable<ChildSubItem[]> {
  return this.subItemObservers$.mergeMap(obs => {
     return obs.find(s => s.subItemTag === subItemTag)
               .viewSubItemSource.asObservable();
     });
}
```

I have few properties which is used to create the BehaviorSubject and the Observable for the BehaviorSubject. I created an observable for the array of SubItemObservers as I need it to be populated first through another service call.

```
private subItemObserversSource = new BehaviorSubject<SubItemObservers[]>([]);
private subItemObservers$: Observable<SubItemObservers[]> = new Observable<SubItemObservers[]>();
```

Here's the class for SubItemObservers:

```
export class SubItemObservers {
    subItemTag: string;
    viewSubItemSource: BehaviorSubject<ChildSubItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ChildSubItem[]>([]);;
}
```

Based on Google search, I need to complete the method to return Observable object. But, I'm not sure how to do that with my solution. Can someone help me on how should I completed the subscription in the method in order to resolve the error. What am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, BehaviourSubject inherits Observable, so probably you don't need 2 streams like that.

Secondly, rxjs6 has a best practice of using `pipe`.

Within getChildSubItem, you can just call `this.subItemObserversSource.pipe(mergeMap...)`.

As soon as you initialise your `subItemObserversSource = new BehaviourSubject` in declaration, you shouldn't get any undefined error.

Also, it would always be nice to double check `obs.find(s => s.subItemTag === subItemTag)` in case it returns `undefined`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, @Ngoc-Nam-Nguyen. It works fine by accessing the observable directly on subItemObserversSource.